# How to match Maven groudId release versions

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a maven project and I just changed my `spring-data-neo4j` dependency version.

It has:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Which was previously

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

So, I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project myproject: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Optional; -> [Help 1]
```

This is because (I think) my 2 dependencies have the same `groupId` but don't pull from the same version of the group.

**Question**

How do I know which version of `spring-data-commons` I should use to match the 5.0.0 version of `spring-data-neo4j`?

**UPDATE**

I fixed my problem by just trying tons of versions until the error went away. This isn't really an answer, but my problem is gone now.

Comment: Please further edit your update or provide an answer for future readers, the goal of this site isn't to solve your problem, it is to allow future readers with similar problems to solve it as well. No one will know how to fix this issue if they find this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with separately defining spring-data-commons 1.12.0.RELEASE as a dependency in your pom.xml

Defining only spring-data-neo4j 5.0.0.RELEASE would transitively get you the belonging version of spring-data-commons which is 2.0.0.RELEASE, but if you also separately define the older spring-data-commons 1.12.0.RELEASE, then it will override the newer transitive dependency version, and will cause the experienced problem; likely because the newer version of neo4j would try to use a spring-data-commons API which has changed between versions 1.12.0.RELEASE and 2.0.0.RELEASE

See the relevant parts of the `mvn dependency:tree` printouts

Defining spring-data-neo4j 5.0.0.RELEASE only

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
```

Defining spring-data-neo4j 5.0.0.RELEASE and also spring-data-commons 1.12.0.RELEASE

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:jar:5.0.0.RELEASE:compile
          (...no transitive spring-data-commons:jar here)
```